# In QGIS Composer, is it possible to draw coordinates next to grid cross markers?

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I know how to add coordinates to the border of the map, both inside and outside. But I was wondering if there's a way to add coordinates next to grid markers, such that when I choose the option to have the cross markers, each cross has coordinates next to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this in QGIS Composer (as of QGIS 2.18.3)

One possible workaround is to create a regular grid of points - in this case, I'm using a UTM grid (EPSG:27000) and created a grid with **Vector > Research Tools > Regular points**, using a + (cross) marker, and label them with an expression like

```
to_int($x) || ',' || to_int($y)
```

In this case I've placed a marker every 5km. The values aren't falling on nice round numbers, because my canvas extent wasn't aligned to a nice round number.

If you want lat/lon coords instead, you might want to use the **round()** and **to_real()** functions in your label expression.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I was hoping there was a way to do it on the composer but this will do!