# How to set initial or last coordinate printed in QGIS composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, composer-manager

Is there a way to set the initial or last coordinate printed in a grid?

Working with UTM coordinates I've been seeing the same problem recurringly (see image). The corners aren't a good place to add reference coordinate, so I want to set a start value, as x = 285950 in this case, and an end value, such as y = 6848950. For this case, offset isn't an option, because I want to preserve values ended in 00 or 50.

[image: map]

---

Edit:

The same thing happens with 'outside frame' setting in label position and even worst, the numbers are cut:

[image: maps]

Comment: could you not use a combination of 'outside frame' on your top and left axes and font size to avoid the label collisions in the corners (then resize page to content)? That's a pragmatic solution but may not be what you want aesthetically. If the labels must be inside the border could you update your question to reflect that?

Comment: @StevenKay edited, but the problem is the same

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/233431/55203)